# LPN over non-binary fields

Tags: finite-field, lwe

With regard to LPN over non-binary fields like $\mathbb{F}_3,\mathbb{F}_5,\cdots$, are there any studies about that ? We also would like to know any articles that have a formal definition of the non-binary LPN.
We know large amount of the binary LPN studies, but why is the non-binary LPN rarely studied ?

We referred to:
[Are LPN and LWE problems equivalent?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/65999/are-lpn-and-lwe-problems-equivalent)

Comment: search 'LPN over large fields'.

Comment: Reading up on this, I was surprised to learn that the seminal “decoding a random linear code is NP-complete” paper [On the inherent intractability of certain coding problems](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/5607/1/BERieeetit78.pdf) only deals with binary codes.

Comment: @filterhash thank you for your comment. I found https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/712.pdf and I will read this one.

Comment: @DanielS With your indication, I realized that. Thank you for your comment.